# WD My Cloud disconnecting from network during file transfer

Tags: networking, hard-drive, hardware-failure, nas, cloud

I bought a WD My Cloud 2 TB and when I opened it for the first time, it offered for me to upgrade to the latest firmware version: 3.04.01. I upgraded, then I started to copy my files into drive. After 2-3 hours of inactivity it disappeared on the network. I tried every way to wake it up: only unplugging it and turning back on again helped. I thought maybe it was an accident, and continued.

The same thing happened a second time. I decided to factory restore. I took about 4-5 hours to full factory reset. I started to copy my data again. The same problem happened during the copy. It disappeared from the network. I tried to click the reset button for 4-5 seconds. Even holding it for 10 seconds didn't start any soft reset. I tried to detach/attach the network cable. I restarted my router. There was only a still blue led light. No blinking or any another color light.

Now what should I do? It's totally unacceptable. I can't trust my data to this drive. What is problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest returning the hard drive to [WD](http://support.wdc.com/) - describe the issues, and they will send you a replacement drive.